# Is there a theoretical foundation behind CSS?

Tags: formal-languages, programming-languages

You know how programming languages can be based on Lambda Calculus or the Turing Machine and SQL is based on relational algebra. Is there any such thing for CSS or any foundation that could be used for styling languages in general if we were to design a new language from scratch?

Styling and layout in general is something I'd expect to be possible to formalize mathematically, at least the layout and positioning part of it.

Comment: Theory is for reasoning about things. What things regarding CSS do you want to reason about? Do you want to optimize CSS? Do you want to perform compliance checking of sites against a stated graphical design specification? Or something else?

Comment: @reinierpost Layout and positioning. For example, consider `flex`. Can any other `display` option such as inline or block be expressed in terms of flex? Not looking for an answer to this question, just giving an example of the kind of questions one may ask. [This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352220817300238) I posted in the comments below is another example.

Comment: Fundamentally it's a query language like SQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a deeper foundation, as CSS is just a lookup table of key value pairs declared under certain rules. It then gets interpreted by the browsers' graphical renderer. From a linguistics perspective, I'd see CSS syntax as the following: `Map<Rule, Map<String, Value>>`, where `Rule` is its own querying or pattern matching statement.

I agree on that CSS seems like a mess sometimes. Especially when you have to re-use some of the rules, key-value pairs multiple times. For those cases, I recommend transpilers like [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/). It allows you to declare rules in a less verbose way, and allows you to encapsulate certain key-value pairs to be able to reuse later.

Comment: I wasn't really asking about the syntax since in that case formal language theory could be the foundation of every language, including CSS. I was asking about the semantics, like how a SELECT in SQL corresponds to some operation in relational algebra, I now wonder if `flex`, for instance, corresponds to some operation in some formal theory

Comment: Well, since it is just a "configuration" language, nothing directly corresponds to any semantics rather than it being a lookup table. It all is a set of configurations for the target renderer (mostly browsers' internal rendering engines for web infrasturcture) @Juan

Comment: For example, a basic key-value pair like `color: #000000` does not correspond to any imperative logic at all. It is just an atomic piece of information, waiting to be read and used on the topic of renderer's. You can arbitrarily write a renderer that takes in a totally made-up `myColor` value of a matching rule, and use it inside the renderer's rendering routine.  As an example, JavaFX (A Java framework) implements its own renderer that attempts to read its made-up keys like `-fx-fill` or `-fx-stroke` and do something with them internally

Comment: But maybe "Box model" is something you are looking for @Juan . Generally CSS configurations are used to flavour the renderers' box model layouting routine. So maybe the things you're looking for are the "Box Model" and "Layouting"?

Comment: Yes to your last comment. I'm not worried about the syntax part of CSS but about the logic of positioning and layout, that's why I also mentioned styling languages in general, not necessarily CSS. I tried to lookup box model and layouting but can't find any theory, just a bunch of CSS specific topics.

Comment: [Here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352220817300238) is something I think could work as a foundation if we were to design a new layout language, which I guess also shows that layout and positioning can be formalized. That also answers the part of my question about layout languages in general, now I just wonder if CSS (the layout/positioning/box modeling part of it) was based in any such formalism. Also to show that my question is not pointless since I was kind of getting that feeling from your reply.

Comment: No no, your question is not pointless at all. Also I think this wikipedia page should also help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layout_(computing) . Since every method/type of layouting has its own guidelines (declared with display key in CSS specifically), getting to know each one might also come in handy. For example, see CSS-tricks' blog post on how Flex layouting works: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox . And of course the official specification of CSSWG: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/

Comment: @iGoodie `color: #000000` is not merely singular (not sure what you mean by atomic but I assume you mean a single piece of information) it is inherited by the children of the DOM node unless overridden. Basically CSS semantics is similar to object oriented programming.

Answer (score 5):

[Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors) and [combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators) from CSS are a form of [combinatory logic](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic). This can be reduced to the [SKI calculus](https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Eodonnell/Teacher/Lectures/Formal_Organization_of_Knowledge/Examples/combinator_calculus/).

I think it is also possible to see CSS rulesets as a form of [lenses](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Lenses_and_functional_references) from functional programming. E.g. a CSS ruleset is a functor of `DOMElement -> DOMElement` which changes how it looks. An empty ruleset would be isomorphic to the `id` function. You could think of `calc` properties as lambda functions, too, I suppose.

Note, I don't know that CSS was intentionally designed with these theoretical foundations. Just that one could use these abstract ideas to understand how/why CSS works in the way that it does.

Comment: As the wisest ones (e.g. SPJ) are used to say: There are five elementary arithmetical operations: addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and monad.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's separate `styles` (which existed **before** css) and `css`.

Styles are just how things should look and I'm not going to delve deeper into it.

CSS on the other hand is a system of applying styles according to rules.

The core concept that CSS introduced is Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP). AOP is used whenever you have a feature that is a cross-cutting concern. That is, when something needs to be used by multiple things not related by type or flow control.

Things that need the same feature/operation within the same flow control can be handled by functions in functional languages or design patterns like command pattern or visitor pattern. This is because there is usually a single logical point in the program that handles the feature.

Things that need the same feature within a set of related types can be handled by inheritance. You can create an abstract parent class that have the feature and inherit from it.

However AOP covers the case when you need to apply a feature to a bunch of different things at different points in the program.

CSS achieves this by the introduction of classes. With classes you can define a set of features (eg. font size, color & padding) and then apply them to various parts of your document.

This is similar to how AOP is achieved in programming languages: either via mixins or decorators.

This is one of the two foundational cores of CSS: the **style sheet** (the "SS" in CSS).

The other part of CSS is style inheritance. There are two aspects of this:

- How styles are inherited by child nodes
- Which style to render when multiple styles are defined

Typically, non-layout styles such as color and font are inherited by child nodes and layout styles such as position and padding are not inherited. So for example a container div with red text and 10px padding will cause all its children to have red text but not the 10px padding.

Once inherited the style can be overridden by applying it to the specific child node by either assigning a class to the node or an id.

A single node may also find itself to be the target of many style definitions. For example a link may find itself to have multiple color defined. Which style is picked is based on a point based priority system.

Styles defined later in the program flow have higher priority (more points). However styles defined with higher level of specificity have even higher priority (eg. a style defined with `div div.container div.content span.announcement` is given more points than one defined with `span.announcement`). Similarly styles defined with id has higher priority than styles defined with class.

Together these make the other part of CSS: the **cascading** rules (the "C" in CSS).

Comment: Object oriented GUI systems have always been using inheritance and delegation of properties. What is nice about CSS, and aspect-oriented if you wish, is that it is separate from the specification of the elements to which it applies. That wasn't a new idea, either; stylesheet languages existed before CSS.